# Insert into one table from another with exist validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have 2 tables:

- Table_Users
- Table_Sites

When I create an entry for `Table_Users` I want to also insert data from `Table_Users` to `Table_Sites` but only if it doesn't exist, the data I want to insert is:

1. Table_Users.userID
2. Table_Users.username
3. Table_Users.site

And column names in Table_Sites which are:

1. Table_Sites.userID
2. Table_Sites.username
3. Table_Sites.siteName

What I need to know is how can I do my SQL within a string to use with the `SqlCommand` in c#.

Comment: Is `Table_Users.userID` auto-generated ID for `Table_Users`?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask]. Hint: you need to show what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this could be sorted out in a pretty straightforward manner:

```
insert into Table_Sites(userID, userName, siteName)
select tu.userID, tu.userName, tu.site
from Table_Users tu
where not exists(select 1 from Table_Sites ts 
  where ts.userID = tu.userID and ts.userName = tu.userName 
    and ts.siteName = tu.site )
```

line breaks are not required so you can put it into a single line if you wish to.

Another way to do same thing is to use `except` which returns only those rows from first select which could not be found in second select:

```
select tu.userID, tu.userName, tu.site
from Table_Users tu

except

select ts.userID, ts.userName, ts.siteName 
from Table_Sites ts
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using PetaPoco.
Available in nuget